# Incrementing / Decrementing database number values by comparing them

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a sponsorship page that I need to display icons for `sponsors_needed` and `sponsors_received`.

Example:

- Sponsors_Needed = ○ (Outlined dot)
- Sponsors_Received = • (Filled dot)

This is what I have as of now, but a few issues going on that I can't seem to correct.

```
@php
$needed ='<span class="circ-outline"></span>';
$received ='<span class="circ"></span>';
@endphp

@foreach(range(0,$sponsorKid->sponsors_needed--) as $i)
    @if($sponsorKid->sponsors_needed = $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed--)
        @if($sponsorKid->sponsors_needed < $sponsorKid->sponsors_received++)
        {!! $received !!}
        @else
        {!! $needed !!}
        @endif
    @endif

    @php $sponsorKid->sponsors_received--; $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed--; @endphp
@endforeach
```

**Issue 1:**

In my table I have: (5/2)

- Needed = 5
- Received = 2

The output is correct, but the order is incorrect.

- I'm getting this: `○ ○ ○ •  •`
- But need this: `• • ○ ○ ○`

If I reverse the values:

```
        @if($sponsorKid->sponsors_needed < $sponsorKid->sponsors_received++)
        {!! $needed!!}
        @else
        {!! $received !!}
        @endif
```

That gives me the output I'm looking for `• • ○ ○ ○`, but if I have 0 received (5/0) I get `• • • • •` all solid. Need all open `○ ○ ○ ○ ○`

**Issue 2:**

I also want to say, "*This person has 3 slots to fill*"

So I do sponsors_needed `-` sponsors_received... Should get `2`
`{{ $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed - $sponsorKid->sponsors_received }}`
I'm getting `-4` ...? (Can't figure out why)

I pretty much got to this point by much trial and error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't do this work in a template, Templates should be strictly for display logic not business logic.  It may also be much easier to figure out outside of the template...  There is no easy way to test this without setting it up in a template etc...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix So try moving this to the controller? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: That's what I would do. Also I am not sure about this line (I don't use laravel or blade) `if($sponsorKid->sponsors_needed = $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed--)` you have a single `=` here not sure if that is intentional or not.  This is probably done as assignment, which you shouldn't have to do with `--`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy... my head hurts... lol

How about something like that? Am I missing something?...

I updated the solution to include your second question... I like to treat my input data as immutable (I dont't change it as I could need it in the page later like you did for calculating the number of slots remaining). So in this case, I did a quick assignments to page scoped variables... $numReceived, which is the copy I will be decrementing instead of the original) and $numNeeded ... for convenience if needed elsewhere... but you could calculate it inline...

Hope this helps

```
@php
$needed ='<span class="circ-outline"></span>';
$received ='<span class="circ"></span>';
$numReceived = $sponsorKid->sponsors_received;
$numNeeded = $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed - $numReceived;
@endphp

@for($i = 0 ; i < $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed ; i++)
    @if($numReceived-- > 0) 
        {!! $received !!}
    @else
        {!! $needed !!}
    @endif
@endfor
<span>This person needs {{ $numNeeded }}</span>
```

Comment: Yes, it's been hurting my head too. Your solution is working great. Thanks for teaching me something new. The only issue I get now is my #2 question. When I try and display the number of slots left, I'm getting `9` on a `5 needed / 1 received. ` IE. Jane currently has `{{ $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed - $sponsorKid->sponsors_received }}` slots left.  It should return 4. (5-1=4) Do you know what the issue is? Seems like it's adding/doubling my sponsors_needed in that simple subtraction equation.

Comment: After a nice game of trial and error, this seems to be outputting the correct leftover slot value `{!! $i++ - $sponsorKid->sponsors_needed - $sponsorKid->sponsors_received !!}` Please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated the answer... Have not tried it but it will give you a starting point... Note that when you do the -- or ++ it actually decrements/increments the value of the variable... that is why I try to make copies when I am going to change the original values... so I treat my page input as immutable as a rule of thumb...